# Verificar se uma string existe em um array

Tags: javascript, array

Escreva uma função que verifique se o vetor de habilidades passado possui a habilidade JavaScript e retorna um booleano true/false caso exista ou não.

```
function temHabilidade(skills) {
 // código aqui
}
var skills = ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "React Native"];
temHabilidade(skills); // true ou false
```

Dica: para verificar se um vetor contém um valor, utilize o método `indexOf()`.

Eu fiz assim:(mas ta dando errado)

```
<script>
         let skills = ["JavaScript", "ReactJS", "Flutter","React Native"] 

         function temHabilidade(skills) {
                if (skills == "JavaScript") {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }

         }
         var resultado = temHabilidade(skills)
         console.log(resultado)

    </script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Você precisa procurar no *array* pelo conteúdo, não pode comprar um *array* com um potencial elemento dele que obviamente dará falso, afinal nem sequer o tipo dos dois dados são iguais, um é uma lista de dados e o outro é o dado singular.

Tem várias formas de fazer isso, eu usei o método pronto [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
function temHabilidade(skills) {
    return skills.includes("JavaScript");
}
let skills = ["JavaScript", "ReactJS", "Flutter","React Native"];
var resultado = temHabilidade(skills);
console.log(resultado);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Includes.js).

Note que eu simplifiquei não fazendo um `if` porque ele já retorna verdadeiro ou falso e não precisa nada mais que isso. Também coloquei `;` porque funciona sem na maioria dos casos, mas não em todos e quando pegar uma situação que não funciona ficará bem perdido, acostume-se fazer do jeito certo sempre, mesmo quando não precisa (aparentemente o enunciado tomou esse cuidado).

Se for usar a dica, que eu não acho boa porque, como poderá perceber no código,  ela precisa de duas operações sem necessidade ou ganho algum, pelo contrário, é mais caro, pode usar o [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
function temHabilidade(skills) {
    return skills.indexOf("JavaScript") != -1;
}
let skills = ["JavaScript", "ReactJS", "Flutter","React Native"];
var resultado = temHabilidade(skills);
console.log(resultado);
```

Quando tem dúvidas consulte a documentação, por isso coloquei *links* para você.

Se o exercício proibisse usar alguma função pronta para ensinar melhor como pensar no algoritmo então pode fazer:

```js
function temHabilidade(skills) {
    for (const item of skills) if (item == "JavaScript") return true;
    return false;
}
let skills = ["JavaScript", "ReactJS", "Flutter","React Native"];
var resultado = temHabilidade(skills);
console.log(resultado);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Contains.js).

Nesse caso eu varri o *array* com o `for` então pegando item por item eu comparo se é o que procura, se for ele encerra com `true`, se ele passar por todo o laço sem encerrar, ou sejam se nenhum item der verdadeiro então ele encerra com `false` já que não achou o que procurava.

Answer (score 9):

Cara é um exercício bem simples, vou deixar a solução, mas não deixe de tentar outras formas para melhorar suas perspectivas e skills;

Tenta assim:

```js
function temHabilidade(skills) {
  return skills.indexOf("Javascript") >= 0;
}

let skills = ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "React Native"];
console.log(temHabilidade(skills));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alguns exemplos de funções para o mesmo exercício:

```js
var skills = ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "React Native"];

// Declaracao de funcao
function temHabilidade1(skills) {
  console.log('Tem habilidade 1:', skills.indexOf('Javascript') != -1);
}

// Arrow function ES6
temHabilidade2 = skills => console.log('Tem habilidade 2:', skills.indexOf('Javascript') != -1)

// Arrow function ES5
var temHabilidade3 = function(skills) {
  return console.log('Tem habilidade 3:', skills.indexOf('Javascript') != -1)
}

// High Ordem Function
const sim = 'Sim';
const nao = 'Não';

function simNao(value) {
  return value === true ? sim : nao;
}

function concatena(value, habilidade = '') {
  console.log(`Dentre as skills (${skills.join(', ')}) existe a habilidade ${habilidade}? ${simNao(value)}.`);
}

function imprime(value, habilidade = '') {
  console.log('Tem habilidade 4:', value);
}

function condicional(test, habilidade, func) {
  if (test) {
    func(true, habilidade);
  } else {
    func(false, habilidade);
  }
}

var temHabilidade4 = function(value, values, func) {
  condicional(values.indexOf(value) >= 0, value, func);
};

temHabilidade1(skills);
temHabilidade2(skills);
temHabilidade3(skills);
temHabilidade4('Javascript', skills, imprime);

// Funcao anonima - for
console.log('Tem habilidade 5:',
  (function() {
    for (const iterator of skills) {
      return iterator.indexOf('Javascript') != -1;
    }
  }())
);

//Funcao anonima
(function() {
  console.log('Tem habilidade 6:', skills.indexOf('Javascript') != -1)
}())

temHabilidade4('Javascript', skills, concatena);
temHabilidade4('Angular', skills, concatena);
```